# is there a way to prevent mac spoofing using debian

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall

I have a debian server that acts as a router for a network, and I am planning on making it so I am able to block network access for certain computers, what do you think would be the best way to do it? I was thinking mac address filtering, although that could be spoofed. I was also thinking of IP filtering, but that could be avoiding just as easily. A few pages on google suggested doing something with arp tables, but im not sure how to go about doing that. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/430381/126632

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go "not constructive" on this one. Exact duplicate is a better fit, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for layer 2 authentication, as in [IEE 802.1X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X), on your switches or wireless access points. There's nothing that you can do on a gateway device (router, firewall, etc) to prevent layer 2 or layer 3 "spoofing". You need an authentication mechanism that operates on the layer 2 device to authenticate trusted devices.